# two button in a form to display a dictionary is not working

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I want to use two buttons in a template form and run two action in a function.
when I omit if with only a button, django runs ,   but when I add if in the codes to execute 2 action , it stops working
in view:
def result(request):
num1 = int(request.GET["num1"])
num2 = int(request.GET["num2"])

```
if 'add' in request.POST:
    res = num1 + num2

if 'sub' in request.POST:
    res = num1 - num2

return render(request, 'home/result.html', {'result': res})
```

in template named clt

```
        <form action="result" >
            Enter 1st number : <input type="text" name="num1"><br>
            Enter 2st number : <input type="text" name="num2"><br>

            <button type="submit" name="subscribe">Subscribe</button>
            <button type="submit" name="unsubscribe">Unsubscribe</button>

        </form>
```

in template named result
 result   : 
 {{ result }}

Answer (score 0):

In the code above your 'if' test does not match the name you have given the buttons. Try:

```
if 'subscribe' in request.POST:
    res = num1 + num2

if 'unsubscribe' in request.POST:
    res = num1 - num2
```

The formatting broke on your code, it looks like you are using GET to get the two variables.  If that's working, no worries, but normally form posted data should be gotten by request.POST.get['num1']